# Samsung Galaxy A20, tried root. No OS installed. Sideload doesn't work

Tags: adb, rooting, root-access, custom-roms, twrp

I was attempting to root and flash Havoc OS on my phone. I am in TWRP and I don't have the havoc OS image on my device's storage. All of my device has been wiped and there is no OS there anymore (rebooting gives me that warning that I shouldn't reboot cause I don't have an OS). Sideload keeps failing to start when I go to Advanced -> Sideload (in TWRP) and I do have the phone connected to the PC with a USB cable but it doesn't show anything in the File Explorer. `adb devices` doesn't list anything in list of connected devices and adb push shows the "no device/emulator found" error. Is my phone bricked? Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flash custom or stock ROM with Odin mode working? (from a bad flashed Galaxy A20, see image)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220805/how-to-flash-custom-or-stock-rom-with-odin-mode-working-from-a-bad-flashed-gal)

Comment: most important is disable AVB therefore flash **blank** vbmeta. also check your bootloader version (last line) make sure to flash only matching ROM (bootloader is not downgradeable, keep lowest possible version you can get)

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4095589

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3910594

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already got help with that a while ago. But still, appreciate that.